# How do you add a LoginRequiredMixin when there's an inconsistent method resolution?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, mixins

I have the following `urls.py` file:

```py
urlpatterns = [
        path('', views.index, name='index'),
        path('account/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls'), name="login"),
        path('signup/', views.SignUp.as_view(), name='signup'),
        path('polls/<int:pk>/', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
        path('polls/<int:pk>/results/', views.ResultsView.as_view(), name='results'),
        path('polls/<int:week_id>/vote/', views.vote, name='vote'),
]
```

And the following views:

```py
@login_required
def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello, there my frined")

class SignUp(CreateView):
   form_class = UserCreationForm
   success_url = reverse_lazy('login')
   template_name = 'registration/signup.html'

class DetailView(LoginRequiredMixin, DetailView):
    model = Week
    template_name = "detail.html"

# Problem is here
class ResultsView(LoginRequiredMixin, DetailView):
    model = Week
    template_name = 'results.html'
```

For some reason the `LoginRequiedMixin` in the `ResultsView` class produces the following error:

```
  File "/Users/user/Projects/cafeteria/weeklydesert/urls.py", line 3, in <module>
    from . import views
  File "/Users/user/Projects/cafeteria/weeklydesert/views.py", line 25, in <module>
    class ResultsView(LoginRequiredMixin, DetailView):
TypeError: Cannot create a consistent method resolution
order (MRO) for bases LoginRequiredMixin, DetailView
```

This is my `results.html`

```html
<h1>Week of: {{ week.coming_monday }}</h1>

<ul>
{% for choice in week.choice_set.all %}
    <li>{{ choice.desert_choice }} -- {{ choice.votes }} vote{{ choice.votes|pluralize }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>

<a href="{% url 'detail' week.id %}">Vote again?</a>
```

The code runs fine when removing the mixin form `ResultsView`, what's wrong with the code?

Comment: Your view just above `ResultsView` is **also** named `DetailView` and it also inherits from `LoginRequiredMixin`. (You likely want to inherit from the generic `DetailView` but you are actually inheriting from the view you also name as `DetailView`)

Comment: Damn it. Thanks!